# How can I make a relation from Table A to table C where A related to B and B is related to C in LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, relation

[image]

How can I able display the info from "set Penalties" Table when I do something like: `$loanApplication->duration->setPenalties->penalty`?

LoanApplication Model:

```
public function loanDuration()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\LoanDuration', 'id','loan_duration_id');
}
```

LoanDuration Model:

```
public function loanApplications()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LoanApplication::class);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. `$loadApplication->loadDuration` should already give you information from the loan_durations table.

In your LoanDuration Model you should add a new relationship method like this:

```
public function setPenalties(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(<Your penalty model>);
}
```

This will allow you to retrieve the penalties from a LoadDuration:
`$loadDuration->setPenalties;`

Or with the full example, the result will be a collection of setPenalties:

```
$loanApplication->loadDuration->setPenalties
```

It could be possible that you wont get any results from the setPenalties. This is because of the name of the related column name in the database. You could either change the name of the column duration_id to loan_duration_id or specify the duration_id in the `$this->belongsTo(<Your penalty model>, 'duration_id')`

Comment: thanks @Bart. I am having this error, Return value of App\LoanDuration::setPenalties() must be an instance of App\BelongsToMany, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany returned (View:

Comment: @Lito Make sure that you use the correct use statement on top of you Model class:
```use App\BelongsToMany;``` should be ```use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;```

Comment: ah I did not put that one. Thanks!

Comment: I follow this, "$this->belongsToMany(<Your penalty model>, 'set_penalties', 'id', 'duration_id')" but after i put this on my blade, {{$loanapplications->loanDuration->setPenalties}} the result is []

Comment: I a'm not sure but this could have something to do with the order of: 'id', and 'duration_id' try to switch them or remove the: 'id'

Comment: I am sorry. The belongsToMany is the wrong method (many to many). It should be: ```return $this->belongsTo(<Your Model>, 'duration_id'); ```

Comment: Done and no problem! Good luck!